# How to install multiple versions of PHP on one server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php

I want to have two versions of `PHP` on one server and switch between them using a symlink.

I have `PHP 5.3.2` installed. I want to install `PHP 1.4.6` along side it and be able to switch back and forth between them eg;

```
/opt/php/5.3.2
/opt/php/5.4.21
/opt/php/live -> /opt/php/5.4.21
```

as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/581985/80757). However I'm struggling to find out how to do this.

I'm using an Ubuntu 10.04 server running Nginx and PHP-FPM/FastCGI.

To my mind `apt-get` seems to want to only have one version of each program so I guess having two versions side-by-side must avoid using `apt-get` or similar utils.

Comment: Not tested yet, but you should be able to specify the php.ini file in nginx.conf.

Comment: I don't think you can specify the `php.ini` file in `nginx.conf`. Nginx passes the HTTP request to PHP using FastCGI ie. ip/port eg. `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000`. To Nginx, PHP is just another server.

Comment: Then setup a few of those, and pass them over. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to compile it yourself.  To get a compilation that is very close to the precompiled Ubuntu you can use the same config flags as in the Ubuntu source package but with a different `--prefix`:

```
    ./configure \
        --prefix=/opt/php/5.3.2 \
        --enable-force-cgi-redirect \
        --enable-fastcgi \
        --disable-debug \
        --with-regex=php \
        --disable-rpath \
        --disable-static \
        --with-pic \
        --with-layout=GNU \
        --with-pear=/usr/share/php \
        --enable-calendar \
        --enable-sysvsem \
        --enable-sysvshm \
        --enable-sysvmsg \
        --enable-bcmath \
        --with-bz2 \
        --enable-ctype \
        --with-db4 \
        --without-gdbm \
        --with-iconv \
        --enable-exif \
        --enable-ftp \
        --with-gettext \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --with-pcre-regex=/usr \
        --enable-shmop \
        --enable-sockets \
        --enable-wddx \
        --with-libxml-dir=/usr \
        --with-zlib \
        --with-kerberos=/usr \
        --with-openssl=/usr \
        --enable-soap \
        --enable-zip \
        --with-mhash=yes \
        --with-system-tzdata \
        --without-mm \
        --with-curl=/usr \
        --with-enchant=/usr \
        --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
        --with-gd=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf \
        --with-gmp=/usr \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
        --with-xpm-dir=/usr/X11R6 \
        --with-png-dir=/usr \
        --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
        --enable-intl \
        --with-ttf=/usr \
        --with-t1lib=/usr \
        --with-ldap=/usr \
        --with-ldap-sasl=/usr \
        --with-mysql=/usr \
        --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config \
        --with-pspell=/usr \
        --with-unixODBC=/usr \
        --with-recode=/usr \
        --with-xsl=/usr \
        --with-snmp=/usr \
        --with-sqlite=/usr \
        --with-sqlite3=/usr \
        --with-mssql=/usr \
        --with-tidy=/usr \
        --with-xmlrpc \
        --with-pgsql=/usr PGSQL_INCLUDE=`pg_config --includedir` \
        --enable-pdo \
        --without-pdo-dblib \
        --with-pdo-mysql=/usr \
        --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr \
        --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/bin/pg_config \
        --with-pdo-sqlite=/usr \
        --with-pdo-dblib=/usr
```

Of course, any of those modules you don't need can be removed from the configure (e.g. if you are never going to use snmp then change `--with-snmp=/usr` to `--without-snmp` or just leave it out altogether)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you out and you can try this without IPSConfig.

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-multiple-php-versions-php-fpm-and-fastcgi-with-ispconfig-3-centos-6.3